# SharePoint 2016 Copy file from page assets to Document set using JavaScript Client Object Model

Tags: file-upload, document-set

I just added a button to my Document Set Home Page that is supposed to copy a fixed small file stored in ../../SiteAssets/min.png and adds it to the documents of this DS.

So far I was able to store in  my DocumentSet Library. Would need to go deeper to current Document set.

I can get the Query Parameters using:

```
//get the querystring from the Document Set url and split into an array
 function getVariables() {  
   var variables = {};  
   var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) { variables[key] = value; });  
   return variables;  
 }  
 //get the items   
 var listID = getVariables()["List"]  
 var rootFolder = getVariables()["RootFolder"];
```

**I need to adjust something here, instead of pointing to 'MyDocumetLibrary':**

```
    // Get the ClientContext for the app web
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //get lib from its name
    var parentList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MyDocumetLibrary");




<script type="text/javascript">  

function createfile (url)   
{  
    var clientContext;  
    var oWebsite;  
    var oList;  
    var fileCreateInfo;  
    var fileContent;  

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();  
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("MyDocmentSetLibrary"); 

    fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
// This just make filename unique       
var filename =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1) + 'Minute.xyz';
        fileCreateInfo.set_url(filename);  
        fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());  
        fileContent = url;  

    for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++)   
    {  
        fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(fileContent.charCodeAt(i));  
    }

    this.newFile = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);  
    clientContext.load(this.newFile);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync( Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));  

    function successHandler()   
    {  
       console.log("FILE CREATED!");
    }  

    function errorHandler()   
    {  
       console.log("File Creation Failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());  
    }  
}  


    </script>
```

http://mysite/sites/mytest/SiteAssets/min.png');" />

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the end this was simply achieved by updating the SP.FileCreationInformation object set url to `fileCreateInfo.set_url("http://mySPServer/sites/mytest/mydocLibrary/MyDocSetName/myfile.txt");`